# TemplateBinding not working with command WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm currently working on a new combobox that has a button called 'Add' that needs to be fire a command when it clicked, Basically it will start a new window to add new row in the database.

I have created a new control that inherits from Combobox and added a new command called 'AddCommand' and then created a Template that will add the new button to the combobox which is called 'Add'. When I bind the command of the button to the 'AddCommand' through TemplateBinding it won't work.

I have created a custom control as follows:

```
    public class ZeroOneCombobox : ComboBox
    {
        public ICommand AddCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return (ICommand)GetValue(AddCommandProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                SetValue(AddCommandProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AddCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("AddCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ZeroOneCombobox));
    }
```

Then I have created a Control Templete As Follows:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ZeroOneComboBoxControl" TargetType="{x:Type zoc:ZeroOneCombobox}"
                         xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Popup Grid.Column="2" x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Name="ItemPanel" IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Popup>

                <Button x:Name="Add" Grid.Column="0" Content="+" Style="{StaticResource ComboboxButton}" Command="{TemplateBinding AddCommand}" />

                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" 
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                              Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                              Grid.Column="2"
                              IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="#FFACACAC" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1"/>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                            <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                                <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="F1M0,0L2.667,2.66665 5.3334,0 5.3334,-1.78168 2.6667,0.88501 0,-1.78168 0,0z" Fill="#FF606060" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFABADB3"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Black"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFEBF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Black"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDAECFC" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDAEBFC" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FFBFBFBF"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFBFBFBF"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                </ToggleButton>
                <TextBox x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="2"
                                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" 
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                                   IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                   SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                   BorderThickness="0"
                                                   IsEnabled="True" 
                                                   IsReadOnly="False"
                                                   IsTabStop="False" />
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

When I bind a command to the ViewModel like follow:

```
 <zoc:ZeroOneCombobox  x:Name="Comb" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Template="{StaticResource AdvComboBoxControl}"
                              AddCommand="{Binding ViewAccountCommand}" Margin="163,234,308.6,154" />
```

The Command won't fire when I click on the add button...

Please help!

Comment: You do not set any command to `AddCommand`, that is why it is not executed.

Comment: Fix last Code, I did set the 'AddCommand' But Still Not Working...

Comment: This should work, maybe your binding does not work, because the data context is wrong. Check your output window for binding or other errors.

Comment: the output did not show any errors

Comment: the output did not show any errors

Comment: I have added a button binding to the same command and working fine, so no problem with the datacontext

Comment: Can you please copy it to your device and test it?

Comment: Apart from the fact that you reference the template with the name `AdvComboBoxControl`, while the key of your template is actually `ZeroOneComboBoxControl`, it works.